# Help with setting for how to stop showing available updates Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS?

Tags: updates, update-manager, notification

I am a complete Linux NOOB, so please elaborate on your answers as if you were explaining to your non-computer-literate elder relative.

I am running multiple instances of Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on mini computers such as Intel NUCs, Gigabytes, and Beelinks, in a remote kiosk setting.

I want to be able to run updates periodically, but on my schedule, not randomly or as they are released. I may be overthinking/not understanding the settings, I think I have everything shut off for seeing updates, but then I get this kind of screen.
[Updates available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG9Iy.png)

First off, I have my notifications set this way "Do Not Disturb" & "Lock Screen Notifications" are on. [Notifications - Do Not Disturb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8I7x.png) Secondly, I have notifications turned off for things that I though might be allowing it, such as the Software Updater notification is set to off. [Software Updater notifications are off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qFHa.png)

Finally, these are the settings in the dialog boxes for Software & Updates. I did not uncheck everything, as I want to be able to run updates when I want, and I assume that if I unchecked everything, it would not run at all? Here are the 7 screens of the dialog with how I have them checked.

[S&U Ubuntu Software, 1st 4 of 5 are CHECKED.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRTFs.png)

[S&U Other, Software Canonicals are UNCHECKED and the Intels are CHECKED.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC1HX.png)

[S&U Updates, Subscribed to ALL, Automatically check is NEVER, When has NO VALUE, When there are other update is TWO WEEKS, Notify me of new versions is NEVER.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94vYf.png)

[S&U Authentication.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKDK0.png)

[S&U Additional Drivers - NONE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg6Se.png)

(I'm unable to post the last two, because I am new to the forum, but here are the settings)

S&U Developer Options - UNCHECKED.

S&U Ubuntu Pro - NOT ENABLED

If you see something obvious, or my understanding of how things work is wrong please tell me. If there is another dialog box that I missed, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: There is (deliberately) no GUI setting to accomplish what you seek.

Comment: @user535733 Ok, so is there a non GUI way? Or should I be using a different variety of Linux for remote purposes?

Comment: Oh sure it can be done. But it's not recommended for beginners (which you have claimed to be). If you Search around, you will find it. This has been asked before, many times.